# How to set global properties for ag-Grid in vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

Given my current configuration and the multiple instances of agGrid throughout my project, I aim to establish a global configuration for agGrid in JavaScript.

```
const gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    rowData: data,
    defaultColDef: {
        sortable: true,
        resizable: false,
        filter: true,
        filterParams: {
            buttons: ['reset', 'apply'],
            closeOnApply: true,
            maxNumConditions: 1
        },
        tooltipValueGetter: (params) => {
            const { value } = params;
            if (value === null || typeof value === 'boolean') return null;
            if (typeof value === 'string' && value.isDate()) return moment(new Date(value)).format('DD MMM YYYY HH:mm');
            return value;
        },
        floatingFilter: true,
        suppressMovable: true,
        cellClass: '!border-none !flex !items-center !text-sm'
    },
    rowHeight: 50,
    suppressDragLeaveHidesColumns: true,
    autoSizeStrategy: {
        type: 'fitGridWidth'
    },
    enableCellTextSelection: true,
    ensureDomOrder: true
}
```

I have tried something like

```
export const gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    rowData: data,
    defaultColDef: {
        sortable: true,
        resizable: false,
        filter: true,
        filterParams: {
            buttons: ['reset', 'apply'],
            closeOnApply: true,
            maxNumConditions: 1
        },
        tooltipValueGetter: (params) => {
            const { value } = params;
            if (value === null || typeof value === 'boolean') return null;
            if (typeof value === 'string' && value.isDate()) return moment(new Date(value)).format('DD MMM YYYY HH:mm');
            return value;
        },
        floatingFilter: true,
        suppressMovable: true,
        cellClass: '!border-none !flex !items-center !text-sm'
    },
    rowHeight: 50,
    suppressDragLeaveHidesColumns: true,
    autoSizeStrategy: {
        type: 'fitGridWidth'
    },
    enableCellTextSelection: true,
    ensureDomOrder: true
}
```

And I think there could be a better way to set global configurations for entire ag Grid

Comment: What exactly are you hoping for in a "better way"? The approach of a global config object seems fine.

Comment: I am using HighCharts also, which provides something like this

`Highcharts.setOptions(globalHighchartsConfig);`

which includes all the properties defined in globalHighchartsConfig to all the instances of Highcharts.